# Do not include a component sling exporter data in page sling exporter - AEM

Tags: jackson, aem, sling, sling-models

We have developed a sling exporter for our Page component which exports all the data for the child components as well (using the `ContainerExporter` method `getExportedItems`). I don't want to include some components in the data, so, for that I have mentioned `@JsonIgnoreType` on the model class of the component which is under a parsys/responsivegrid under my page's `jcr:content`. But still, the component's data is getting included. How can I skip a component completely? Is there any annotation available which I can add to my class?

Comment: From Jackson perspective, we can put it in below way:
Let's say we have a `Map<String, ComponentExporter>`. `ComponentExporter` is an interface which has 2  implementations:

1.) `Component1`.
2.) `Component2`.

`Component1` class has the `@JsonIgnoreType` annotation at the class level. Now if we serialize this map, it is not excluding the Component1 object. How can we do that?

Comment: can you provide more details about your component sling model , what are the annotations used?

Comment: Please add some code... That might get you some answers in the end.

Comment: @rajumuddana, It is exactly similar to the core Page component.

@Model(
  adaptables = {SlingHttpServletRequest.class},
  adapters = {Page.class, ContainerExporter.class},
  resourceType = {"core/wcm/components/page/v2/page"}
)
@Exporter(
  name = "jackson",
  extensions = {"json"}
)
public class PageImpl implements ContainerExporter